# C++ Class/Vector pointer problems

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to use a vector of pointers of a class. When trying to access any of the members of the Agent class, I either get a bad pointer or null data. The code is the following.

```
class Grue : public Agent
{
    string name;
    Room *cur_room;
 public:
   Functions()....
};

class Agent
{
        Room *cur_room;
        string name;
  public:
         Functions()....
};


Grue* Grue1 = new Grue("Test", roompointer);
vector<Agent*> agents;
agents.push_back(Grue1);
```

Comment: You don't have to redeclare every data member in your Grue derived class

Comment: what is the error you're getting? Are you declaring the destructor for Grue virtual?

Comment: You should be following the Rule of Three/Five. Vectors copy around data a lot. I suspect this is where your problems are coming from. Also, you must inherit from a complete type, which you haven't done in defining `Agent` after `Grue`.

Comment: Errors include bad pointers when attempting to make calls and no data for things such as agent->name.

Comment: As @lezebulon pointed out, you only need to declare once members `cur_room` and `name`.

Comment: From your code, you should probably read up a bit on inheritance. lezebulon's comment really points it out.

Comment: The most likely problem is that by re-declaring the members in the derived class, the members in the base class never get initialized.  Then you access the members through base class pointers, which means you access the uninitialized members of the base class.  Since they are uninitialized, you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: I should have renamed the Grue class cur_room. They aren't the same thing. The Grue one is the starting Room pointer. That still doesn't fix the issue of why agent->name is nothing.

Comment: @Chris Hayden Thank you. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @JohnGhotti Reading involves focusing your eyes on a text while concentrating on it's semantics in order to absorb the information encoded in the text.

Comment: @ChrisHayden : I'm not sure how it's possible that re-declaring the members in the derived class make the members in the base class not initialize correctly when constructing the base object

Comment: could you post the code for constructor of 'Grue' and 'Agent' and destructor if any ?

Comment: @lezebulon he is not calling the base object constructor but the child's one. Probably not passing the informations to the base constructor.

Comment: @lcfseth : fair enough, I assumed that the base constructor would be called with the same parameters during construction of the derived object

Answer (score 4):

Data members are private by default in a class. Thus your **cur_room**, **name** variables are different in the Agent and Grue class.
When you call the Grue constructor, the Grue fields are initialized, but the vector stores Agent pointers, therefor you are accessing the agent fields which are not initialized.

here's the correct way of doing this:

```
class Agent
{
protected:
    Room *cur_room;
    string name;
public:
    Agent(string n, Room * r)
    : cur_room (r), name(n)         
    {}
};

class Grue : public Agent
{

public:
    Grue(string n, Room * r):Agent(n,r)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: This is correct, but a bit misleading. Whether the Agent members are private, protected, or public wouldn't change the fact that Grue is hiding them with members of the same name. (Also, if you're going to give someone sample code, you really should use member initializers in the ctor instead of assignment in the body.)